# Ubuntu 22.04 hostname not detected from DNS

Tags: networking, network-manager, 22.04, hostname, systemd-networkd

I have been having an issue with Ubuntu 22.04 not detecting the hostname from the DNS server.

I have tried using both the networkd and NetworkManager backends and the server's hostname still appears to be 'localhost'.

My netplan file is identical to our 20.04 build, where the hostname is detected without any problems. I have tried adding the following lines to my netplan config file and then running netplan apply.

```
dhcp4-overrides:
   use-hostname: true
```

Has anybody else come across this problem and managed to resolve it? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since I've never seen an accurate write up on this, this it the correct way to set hostname and FQDN in Ubuntu Server 22.04.

This is also the valid way for all native daemons to detect your correct hostname and FQDN (such as Apache, nginx, and most other correctly implemented services).

### Procedure

This will update /etc/hostname for you.

```
sudo hostnamectl hostname [hostname]
```

Edit /etc/hosts

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 [fqdn] [hostname]
[INTERFACE IP] [fqdn] [hostname] [additional cname fqdn] [additional cname hostname]
```

Example /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 myhost.example.com myhost
192.168.0.100 myhost.example.com myhost myalias.test.com myalias
```

This part is good practice, but is not needed if you are **not** using static IP and have correctly configured DHCP.

/etc/netplan/[your interface netplan file, E.g. 00-installer-config.yaml]:

```
network:
...
    nameservers:
    ...
        search:
            - [yourdomain E.g. example.com]
```

*Be careful editing netplan if you don't know what you are doing and don't have another way into your system besides SSH.*

### Validate

```
hostname
```

output: `myhost`

```
hostname -f
```

output: `myhost.example.com`

Check if you can ping another system on your domain using just it's hostname (not its FQDN):

```
ping otherhost
```

**If hostname and hostname -f do not output correctly then something is wrong.** This is true of all Linux hosts.

Reboot to be safe so all services pickup and restart with the correct information:

```
sudo reboot
```

Validate one more time to make sure everything survived after reboot.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).